# How proves rigurously that Fourier transform of $f(x)=x$ is $i\delta'$

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I know that $\widehat{1}=\delta$ with $\delta$ dirac delta function, and 1 tempered distribution.

Now, $\delta=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i\xi x}1dx\Rightarrow \delta'=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}-ixe^{-i\xi x}dx=-i\widehat{f}$ with $f(x)=x$
The above is not rigorous at all. How can I rigorously proves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's easy to show that the formula $\widehat{xu} = i\hat{u}'$ is valid for a distribution $u$.

The Fourier transform $\hat{u}$ of a distribution $u$ is defined by
$\langle \hat u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \hat \varphi \rangle$
for every test function $\varphi.$ This implies
$$
\langle \widehat{xu}, \varphi \rangle
= \langle xu, \hat\varphi \rangle
= \langle u, x\hat\varphi \rangle
= \langle u, -i\widehat{\varphi'} \rangle
= -i \langle \hat u, \varphi' \rangle
= i \langle \hat u', \varphi \rangle
.
$$
Thus, $\widehat{xu} = i\hat{u}'.$ Taking $u=1$ gives $\widehat{x} = i\delta'.$